# Understand Opentracing Standard and Tracers Providers

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing, jaeger

I'm studying the Opentracing Standard and reading the docs I didn't found the API default Endpoints that should be used by Tracer Providers (Jaeger, LightStep...).

Today I'm using Spring Cloud Sleuth to send metrics do Zipkin, and now I have the option to use Opentracing (brave), but How Spring Cloud Sleuth will know the correct API URL if Opentracing docs don't have a API URL standard.

**i.e:** Jaeger and LightStep (both Opentracing providers) have different API URL.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTracing does not define the concrete data model, how the data should be collected, nor how it should be transported. As such, there's no specification for the endpoint. This allows implementations like Jaeger to use non-HTTP transport by default when sending data from the client (tracer) to the backend, by sending UDP packets to an intermediate "Jaeger Agent".

Given that the base model is pretty much similar among implementations, it's common to have tracing solutions to support each other's endpoints. For instance, Jaeger is able to expose an endpoint with [Zipkin compatibility](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.13/getting-started/#migrating-from-zipkin).

Based on your question, I think you might be interested in the OpenTelemetry project, a successor to the OpenTracing project, as the result of a merge with the OpenCensus project. OpenTelemetry provides its own tracer and is able to "receive" data in several formats (including Jaeger), and "export" to several backends.

Comment: So, opentracing just define the payload model ? Is that ?

Comment: OpenTracing just defines the instrumentation API that your business application uses ("what to trace").